# How do I extract the contents of a specific json within the html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to extract the specific JSON from the HTML head, as below.

I've tried combination of

```
$(".article-body")
```

and

```
$("head")
```

All without much luck - can someone please have a look and see what would be the best solution?

[image: HTML]

Comment: Why not assign the object into a variable?

Comment: I've tried that without luck - so any help would be appreciated mate! :)

Comment: Check my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a reference to the `script` element and then access its `innerText` property. Check out the following snippet:

```js
// get the inner text from the script element by id
    let scriptElem = document.getElementById('json-data');

    // or by tag name
    // make sure to select the correct one from the array of elements
    // to accomplish this you may check if(scriptElem.type == 'application/ld+json')
    // let scriptElem = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

    // parse it to a JSON
    let parsedJson = JSON.parse(scriptElem.innerText);
    console.log(parsedJson)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="application/ld+json" id="json-data">
        {
            "some": "data"
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>JSON from script tag</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// [0] get the first script tag with type 'application/ld+json'
JSON.parse($("script[type='application/ld+json']")[0].textContent)
```